# @Transactional rollback along with @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I am building web app with `spring-mvc` and hibernate. My question is, does `@Transactional` guarantee that it will do rollback even tough the exception is caught by `@ExceptionHandler` method in our `@Controller` ?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation? I assume it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `@Transactional` scope is "tighter", so it will always be handled before `@ExceptionHandler` gets its turn. You could look inside the Spring source code to see how it's done, but it would basically be a massive flaw if other logic were able to run before the transactional context had finished its job, whether commit or rollback.